# Slider Change Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a range slider dynamically and I'm having trouble getting the change handler on it working.

So it's like this in the code:

```
$('#layersTab').html("<input type=\"range\" id=\"layerSlider\" value=\"0\" min=\"0\" max=\"100\" \><br\>");
```

And yeah in the html its:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" id="titlePaneLayers" data-dojo-props="title: 'Layers and Legend'" open="false">
          <div id="layerTabs" >
            <ul></ul> 
          </div>       
</div>
```

How do I add a an event handler to this, so when the slider is changed I can get the values its changed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can us the [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and do this:

```
$('#layersTab').on('change', '#layerSlider', function(e){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```